# Python regex find words with specified character in middle of word not beginning or ending with character.

Tags: python, regex

Hey guys I'm trying to find all words with a specific character in the middle of the word. The word cannot begin or end with the specified character.
lets use 'x' for example. My current regex looks like this:

```
r'\b(?!x)\w+x(?<!x)\b'
```

the \w+x is not returning any results. Anyone have an idea why?

Comment: What you mean by *in the middle*? Can you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?

Comment: Why don't you use the negated character class `[^x]` instead of look ahead/behind?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> z = 'hello welxtra xcra crax extra'
>>> re.findall(r'[^x ]\w*x\w*[^x ]', z)
['welxtra', 'extra']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
import re
print re.match(r'[^]+x+[^]','provxa')
print re.match(r'[^]+x+[^]','xprova')
```

Output:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10eaa0bf8>
None
```

where `[^]` is any char. So it will basically match an 'x' only is it between something else. You can change `[^]` with `[a-z]` to specify lowercase letters instead any char.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(?!x)\w+x\w+(?<!x)\b

            ^^
```

You missed the `\w+`after `x`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/34